# Python 3: Monkey-patched code not re-importable by multiprocessing

Tags: python, import, python-3.x, multiprocessing, monkeypatching

### In Brief

How can I monkey patch module A from module B when module A's functions are supposed to be importable so that I can run the module A's functions with the `multiprocessing` standard library package?

### Background

A client requested a hotfix that will not be applicable to any of our other clients, so I created a new branch and wrote a separate module just for them to make merging in changes from the master branch easy. To maintain the client's backward compatibility with pre-hotfix behavior, I implemented the hotfix as a configurable setting in the app. Thus I didn't want to *replace* my old code -- just patch it when the setting was turned on. I did this by [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717506/if-monkey-patching-is-permitted-in-both-ruby-and-python-why-is-it-more-controve).

### Code Structure

The `__main__` module reads in the configuration file. If the configuration turns on the hotfix's switch, `__main__` patches my `engine` module by replacing a couple of functions with code defined in the `hotfix` module -- in essence, the function being replaced is the [key function to a maximization function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#max). The `engine` module later loads up a pool of [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html) workers.

### The Problem

Once a `multiprocessing` worker gets started, the first thing `multiprocessing` does it [re-imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7994465/1286628)* the `engine` module and looks for the key function that `__main__` had tried to replace (then `multiprocessing` hands over control to my code and the maximization algorithm begins). Since `engine` is being re-imported by a brand new process and the new process does not re-run `__main__` (where the configuration file gets read) because that would cause an infinite loop, it doesn't know to re-monkey-patch `engine`.

### The Question

How can I maintain modularity in my code (i.e., keeping the hotfix code in a separate module) and still take advantage of Python's `multiprocessing` package?

* Note my code has to work on Windows (for my client) and Unix (for my sanity...)

Comment: +1, nicely formatted question. But doesn't `multiprocessing` reimport `__main__` in child processes?

Comment: @nneonneo, yes but rerunning `__main__.main()` would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Sure, sure. But can't you have separate `read_config` and `main()` methods, and call `read_config` but not `main()`?

Comment: How do I get `__main__` to figure out whether it is being loaded as a `multiprocessing` worker or from the command line?

Comment: See my answer. I believe that should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a place where monkey-patching just won't work. It's easier to just extract the functions in question to a separate modules and have engine import them from there. Perhaps you can have a configuration setting of where to import them from.

Another way to modularize this is to use some sort of component architecture, like [ZCA](http://www.muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html). That last option is what I would go with, but that's because I'm used to it, so there is no extra learning for me.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work on a UNIX/Linux OS which has `fork()`, you don't need to do anything special since the new process has access to the same (monkey-patched) classes as the parent.

To make it work on Windows, have your `__main__` module read the configuration on import (put the `read_config`/`patch_engine` call at global scope), but do the multiprocessing (engine execution) in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard.

Then, the read-config code will be performed whenever `__main__` is imported (either from the command-line or from a `multiprocessing` reimport), but the `if __name__ == '__main__'` code is performed only when your script is invoked from the command line (since `__main__` is reimported under a different name in the child process).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are going to have to modify `engine.py` to check a configuration file, and have it patch itself if it's needed.

To work on both unix and Windows `engine` can keep a global `CONFIG_DONE` variable to decide if it needs to check again for the configuration file.